# How to remove the bias term for a standard GRU cell? LSTM/GRU without bias term

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

Does anybody know how to implement a standard LSTM/GRU cell in tensorflow without the bias term? The standard implementation, for example `tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell` does not have an argument for creating the cell without bias terms.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

For GRU, I guess you could remove the two lines of code related to the bias term:

`gate_inputs = nn_ops.bias_add(gate_inputs, self._gate_bias)
...
candidate = nn_ops.bias_add(candidate, self._candidate_bias)`

together with the two bias variables.